# Using jsoup to Post form after onButtonClick

Tags: jsoup

Why does this code not return what I need, it just returns page information from whence I submit, but it does not show search results.

I have a class that extends AsyncTask which executes after I have clicked on a button.. However it does not return search results but rather it returns unnecessary html data. Pls help.

Website : https://eservices.cipc.co.za/Search.aspx

```
public class doAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    View mview;
    Document searchResults;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String url="https://eservices.cipc.co.za/Search.aspx";

        try {
            //Connect to a website
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .timeout(20000)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            //Find the form
            Document responseDocument = response.parse();
            Element potentialForm = responseDocument.select("form#aspnetForm").first();
            checkElement("form Element",potentialForm);
            FormElement form = (FormElement) potentialForm;

            // Fill the form and submit it
            Element ListSearchType = form.select("[name$=ctl00$cntMain$drpSearchOptions]").first();
            checkElement("Search type list",ListSearchType);
            ListSearchType.attr("dropdownSearch","dropdownSearch");

            //Name search
            Element txtBxNameSearch =form.select("[name$=ctl00$cntMain$txtSearchCIPC]").first();
            checkElement("name search txt box",txtBxNameSearch);
            txtBxNameSearch.val("K2019");

            //Submit the form
            searchResults = form.submit().cookies(response.cookies()).post();

            //Extract results
           searchResults.select("table[id$=ctl00_cntMain_gdvNames] > tbody > tr > td");
           System.out.println(searchResults.text());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        mview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.results, null);
        TextView tvView = mview.findViewById(R.id.txtV);
        Button btn2 = mview.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        tvView.setText(searchResults.text());

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });
        alert.setView(mview);
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
public static void checkElement(String name, Element element)
{
    if(element == null)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("unable to find "+name);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to return any data for `K2019`

Comment: I have noticed, is there something, somewhere that I overlooked maybe?